# SQL MIN and MAX relations in SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am retrieving columns from a SQL table using the following code -

```
MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAM",                 
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAMSchoolName",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, bd.StartTime, 100), 7)) + '-' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bd.EndTime, 100), 7)), 'AM',''), 'PM', '') ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAMTimes",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAMTotalChargeAmount",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAMTotalPayAmount",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAMBandBookedAt",

            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAM2",                    
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAM2SchoolName",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, bd.StartTime, 100), 7)) + '-' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bd.EndTime, 100), 7)), 'AM',''), 'PM', '') ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAM2Times",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAM2TotalChargeAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAM2TotalPayAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Monday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "MondayHourlyAM2BandBookedAt",
```

When this code runs, I get the 2 bookings, however the Charge/Pay rates returned are for the other booking. ie -

Should be
Booking 1-  Charge £20, Pay £10
Booking 2-  Charge £100, Pay £50

But Im getting
Booking 1 - Charge £100, Pay £50
Booking 2 - Charge £20, Pay £10

Im thinking this is because its returning the highest and lowest as im using MAX and MIN. How can I relate the MAX and MIN values returned to the "HourlyAM" column?

Hope I explained this well! Thanks

Comment: given almost all of the case statements have identical logic, you really should move the common clauses out of the cases and into the query's primary `where` clause.

Comment: This is a small section of a much larger query. Each day of the week has 6 of these paragraphs, similar but for different duration's (IE: AM, PM, FullDay, AMHourly, PMHourly, FullDayHourly). I realize its not the most efficient way of doing it but it seems to work well and is quick. Therefore I don't think I can move the common clauses in to the primary where clause. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to try to wade through your criteria without a better understanding of your data, but I think you'd be better served using a ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MondayHourlyAMTimes DESC) 'Booking1'
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MondayHourlyAMTimes ) 'Booking2'
       FROM Table
       WHERE common criteria
     )
WHERE Booking1 = 1 OR Booking2 = 1
```

The idea here is that you assign a ranking for each row that meets your criteria based on one field, then return the full row based on that rank.